# Remove json records with same value

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hello guys I have a Json file like this.

```
[
    {
        "port": 8001,
        "password": "test123",
        "method": "aes-256-cfb"
    },
    {
        "port": 8002,
        "password": "123test",
        "method": "aes-256-cfb"
    },
    {
        "port": 8003,
        "password": "234test",
        "method": "aes-256-cfb"
    }
]
```

I have a variable `$q_port` that is 8002, I have to remove from the json file the `"port", "password", "method" WHERE "port" = "$q_port"`, this to get a json file like this.

```
[
    {
        "port": 8001,
        "password": "test123",
        "method": "aes-256-cfb"
    },
    {
        "port": 8003,
        "password": "234test",
        "method": "aes-256-cfb"
    }
]
```

My idea is to do something like this.

```
$myFile = "01.json";
$q_port = "8002";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);
$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

now i dont know how to remove the 3 values

$arr_data = $arr_data = json_decode($arrdata, true);
if(file_put_contents($myFile, $arr_data)) {
        echo "Data successfully saved";
        }
```

Do someone know how to remove the 3 values corresponding to the port?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your array, if the port matches unset it. Then reset the index and json_encode, with pretty print.

```
<?php
$myFile = "01.json";
$q_port = "8002";
$jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);
$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

// loop over each item, if it contains your port, unset it.
foreach ($arr_data as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['port'] == $q_port) {
        unset($arr_data[$key]);
    }
}

// reset the index, prettify back into json
$arr_data = json_encode(array_values($arr_data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

if (file_put_contents($myFile, $arr_data)) {
    echo "Data successfully saved";
}
```

Comment: That works like a charm, Today I have learned that unset a single field with reindex removes the entire "group" of items on the array. In this case unset port deletes the also password and method.

Comment: dont forget JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, so pretty... glad to help, dont forget to upvote

Comment: Perfect!! I'm trying to vote but a message appears, Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: np, 18 rep now ;p

Answer (score 0):

Just re-index the array by the `port` and unset that key:

```
$arr_data = array_column($arr_data, null, 'port');
unset($arr_data[$q_port]);
```

`$arr_data` will still be indexed by the `port`, so if that is a problem just re-index from `0`:

```
$arr_data = array_values($arr_data);
```

**NOTE**:  You might want to leave it indexed by `port` and then you don't have to do the above every time.

Then you want to encode not decode:

```
$arr_data = json_encode($arr_data);
if(file_put_contents($myFile, $arr_data)) {
    echo "Data successfully saved";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `array_filter` function:

```
...
$q_port = "8002";
$arr = json_decode($jsondata);
$result = array_filter($arr, function($o) use($q_port){
    return $o->port != $q_port;
});

file_put_contents($myFile, json_encode(array_values($result)));
```